# codeigniter: changing .txt file in certain area

Tags: codeigniter, anchor

I am making a notebook, with logging in, and writing notes. All info must be stored to text file (I know it is more simple with DB, but it is project requirement to store to file).

So far I have done log in, creating new members, adding new notes. I need to make that notes editable now.

As I am showing all notes in view (then user logs in) I add an anchor to these notes that belongs to logged in user, that says "edit".

```
        foreach ($notes as $item)
    {
        if ($item['user'] == $name) // if post belongs to logged in user, I add "edit"
        {
             echo "<h3>", $item['user'], " " ,$item['date'], "</h3>";
             echo "<p>", $item['content'], " ", anchor('site/edit_note', 'Edit'), "</p>";                
        } 
        //if posts belongs to other users, notes are just posted
              else { 
                   echo "<h3>", $item['user'], " " ,$item['date'], "</h3>";
                   echo "<p>", $item['content'], "</p>";
               }   
    }
```

My text file structure:

```
some user : some user post : date
```

I guess I need to pass some info with these anchors, to make them unique and to know where to edit in a file and to make that post shown in text area form. I have read about URI class and URL helper, but not sure is that what I need?

Later I guess I will do some arrays of file info, rewrite the post I need in array and then store array in a file or something. I just want to know is this the right way to do that?

Comment: I know you mentioned the requirements were to store to a file, but is there any reason this file can't be dynamically generated when requested? That is, store the info in the database and generate the text file in the format you mentioned whenever it's requested.

Comment: well probably I can do that, but I want to avoid using DB. My users info is stored in a file too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should change the file structure to also have a unique ID for each row/post:

```
unique id : some user : some user post : date
```

Then, you can set the url like this:

```
echo "<p>", $item['content'], " ", anchor('site/edit_note/'.$item['id'], 'Edit'), "</p>";
```

and your edit_note method will need to accept an ID parameter

```
function edit_note($requested_id = null)
{
    if (!$requested_id) { return ""; }
    // get the requested id item from your file, that is below

    // The [`file()` function][1] will return the contents of a file as an array. 
    // Each array item will be a line of the file. So if each of your posts are a 
    // line, then you can just do:

    $rows = file('file/path/here');

    //Filter the $rows array to view just the ID needed
    $selected_row = array_filter($rows, function($row) use ($requested_id) {
        $row_items = explode(' : ', $row);
        return ($row_items[0] == $requested_id); 
    });

    $row_items = explode(' : ', $selected_row);

    // now you'll have the contents of the requested post in the $row_items array
    // and can call a view and pass it that data
    $data['row_items'] = $row_items;
    $this->load->view('edit_view', $data);
}
```

Comment: yeah, I was thinking about that unique id in my text file too, but when user adds new post it is just written to the end of the file, how to make that id unique every time user adds a note?

Comment: You can use the same concept to get the last row from the text file, get the id from that row, then just increment that number for the new ID.